# unknown issue with objects

Tags: python, pygame

http://pastebin.com/BAtd71H7
When when i press any mouse button, nothing happens.
I know that the problem is that, there is no bullet to be found inside the list: bullets.
The exact method worked with my other project, but not with this.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please try to ensure that you're providing an MCVE, per http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- that means a **minimal, complete, verifiable** example. "Complete" and "verifiable" meaning it contains everything anyone would need to be able to run it with their proposed fix and see if the problem is solved, and "minimal" meaning it contains nothing that isn't needed to reproduce the problem.-

Comment: Since the actual problem itself isn't related to pygame, you should be able to remove the dependency without removing the problem, thus making the issue much easier to demo to folks without that rather-heavyweight dependency. Similarly, you should be able to test whether the `bounce()` call is needed to reproduce it, and remove it if it's not; likewise for the others pieces of the code, until your example contains everything needed to reproduce the problem, *and nothing that isn't needed to reproduce the problem*.

Comment: ...so, you *would* need to show the code you're using to create the list of bullets, for instance, since that's part of what would be needed to actually show the issue.

Comment: The `bounce()` method is referencing global variables `width` and `height` (I assume). What are their values and where are the set? I also assume the `bullets` list is a global variable, too. If you showed more of your code we could determine these things ourselves (and determine if they're part of the problem).

Comment: It's not the bounce()...

Comment: @Charles Duffy Now there is the whole code.

Comment: Oh, i just played with the code and found that the screen was filled with color AFTER the bullets were displayed!

Answer (score 0):

Jorma Jarppinen got it, you need to move your loop through Bullets <51> to after the screen fill <71>. Hope that works out for you.